# LyX table: "Misplaced \noalign" error in colored multicolumn row

Tags: tables, lyx, multicolumn, colortbl, rowcolor

I found out how to color table cells/columns/rows thanks to the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184461/adding-background-color-to-table-cells-in-lyx) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15145/background-for-table-cells-in-lyx).

I followed the examples in the documentation. In the preamble, I put:

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
```

And at the beginning of the row, I put a TeX box with:

`\rowcolor{lightgray}`

It does work, i.e. the table is generated with the desired color, but LyX always displays a bunch of "Misplaced `\noalign`" errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

In my case, the problem was that the "row" I wanted to color was a *multicolumn row*, so it wasn't actually a real "row" anymore, but only one big, single cell.

Thus, I needed to use `\cellcolor{lightgray}` instead of `\rowcolor{lightgray}`.

## Solution 2

This problem also occurs when you accidentally format the ERT / TeX code, for example by making it bold like this:

[image]

Select the whole ERT (not just the contents, but the whole red box). Remove the formatting, for example by pressing Ctrl+B, so it looks like this again:

[image]